# Spritesheet or Separated PNGs?

Tags: animation, memory-management, lua, love2d

So, I'm working on a small indie game, and for that I made my own animation system, it's pretty efficent at the moment, but I have some doubts about how it'll operate, after I add 20-30-100 more animations, because (as the title says) every single frame is a different image, in a separated folder.

So the question is: How will this work, after I add more animations? Will it cause longer loadtimes, or worse performance? I'm not totally sure, because eg. the file size of the same animation on a spritesheet and if separated, are almost the same.

Comment: This question is likely much too vague to get a real response. There are too many things left unspecified and likely far too many confounding sources of performance changes to be able to pinpoint anything very accurately. The question is likely going to come down to where you fetch the data for each animation from on each frame and how quickly that can respond to randomized access across all your images. (Though note that I am neither a game developer nor a animator/graphics programmer.)

Comment: yeah well, the question is more like: "which one do you think is more efficent?" and I wanted to know if anyone has real experiences with this topic

Comment: That was the point of the first part of my comment. Without significantly more detail about OS, filesystem, memory size, disk speed, disk cache, RAM speed, etc. I don't think there are any True answers. Other than the statement that memory is generally faster than other (disk/etc.) I/O access.

Comment: But my question is not about finding out if it works on a specific computer, I'm asking about average users and if the first method or the other method is more efficent or they are the same, I dont want to know a concrete fps value, I want to know if the other one is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you should ask yourself when making this sort of decision is "what is the cost of switching if I chose the simpler solution now, and need the complex solution later"?

In this case, switching involves:

1. Switching your animation system to use the sprite sheet instead of the individual images. This can be really easy if you make your resource fetching and animation calls clean interfaces, and is not too bad unless you do something really horrible in your code.
2. Getting a program that combines your individual sprites into spritesheets. A quick google search will find dozens of simple programs that do this, but if you need to write your own for some reason it shouldn't be that bad either.

So, my non-answer answer is *you probably should not care* and *if you still care, just take an hour or two and try both*.

Comment: Oh well, because my game is still in its early stages I can still switch from one to the other, but if it makes no difference then i might stick with the current one. Or I might keep it for later. Actually it's easier to use/code/create spritesheet based animations, but what if i want to do something more complex with those images later that might need separated images. eg. if I want to change dimensions of a specific frame, then i might need the current solution. So i think i'll keep the current one.